# using redis with node giving error

Tags: node.js, redis, key-value-store

while running this https://github.com/fictorial/redis-node-client/blob/master/test/test.js#L1093-1097
giving me error :

```
/redis-node-client/test$ node test.js
........................................
node.js:178
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
undefined
```

why this error is coming ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

redis-node-client is deprecated and abandoned by the author.

I would suggest using node_redis: https://github.com/mranney/node_redis

The real reason is probably due to some changes in node.js (version v0.4.8 as of this writing) as the plugin was not updated since June 14th, 2010 (nearly an entire year).